# Phalcon vs Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phalcon

Начал программировать на Symfony - многие хвалят и вроде всё хорошо. Но только по производительности что-то медленная. (То ли у меня с компом что-то, но вроде и не самый старый, но страница порой даже (!) с локалхоста может 5-8 секунд грузиться.)

Читал, что Phalcon. Пишут - один из самых быстрых.
Стоит его использовать?

В чём недостатки и плюсы относительно Symfony?

Comment: Тут зависит от цели, для которой вы ищите фреймворк. А по задаче уже можно подбирать и сравнивать. Phalcon тоже не панацея

Answer (score 3):

Извиняюсь, что напишу не по теме вопроса, но смотрите отладчик в хроме, что именно у вас грузится по 5-8 секунд. Или можете запустить сайт с app_dev.php, там будет написано сколько Symfony грузит страницу, мне кажется, проблема всё таки не в Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony в dev-окружении - очень медленная, потому что каждый раз пересчитывает контейнер, много пишет в логи. Если использовать в сочетании с Vagrant, который очень медленно работает с файловой системой в расшаренных папках.

Можно перейти на Ubuntu - там будет всё работать намного быстрее. В production тоже всё работает очень быстро.

В Windows+Vagrant можно оптимизировать - например, перенести `APP/var/cache` в `/dev/shm/YourAppName/var/cache`. Но хорошо бы и в файлах иметь построенный контейнер, потому что PhpStorm из него берёт данные для автодополнения и валидации кода. У меня в `app/AppKernel.php`:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->getVarOrShmDir('cache/' . $this->getEnvironment());
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return $this->getVarOrShmDir('logs');
}

private function getVarOrShmDir($dir)
{
    $result = dirname(__DIR__) . '/var/' . $dir;

    if (
        in_array($this->environment, ['dev', 'test'], true) &&
        empty($_GET['warmup']) && // to force using real directory add ?warmup=1 to URL
        is_dir($result) && // first time create real directory, later use shm
        file_exists('/bin/mount') && shell_exec('mount | grep vboxsf') // only for VirtualBox
    ) {
        $result = '/dev/shm/' . 'YourAppName' . '/' . $dir . '/' . $this->getEnvironment();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Можно в `php.ini` сделать, чтобы больше использовало кеш, а не диск:

```
realpath_cache_size = 4096k
realpath_cache_ttl = 7200
```

Можно отключить Xdebug:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

Answer (score 0):

по скорости работы phalcon быстрее любого php фрейворка так как phalcon предоставляется как расширение к php. 
Но стоит учесть тот факт, что скорость разработки на phalcon медленнее. Также для него доступно меньше плагинов.
Реальные тесты показывают что он быстрее на 15-20 процентов по сравнению с симфони или yii и всего на 10% чем laravel которые я тоже делал.
В основном верь выигрыш в роутинге, и phalcon просто идеален для restAPI приложений. Также phalcon достаточно простой.
Мне нравится phalcon однако бывают проблемы с реализацией.

Answer (score 0):

Скорость phalcon будет иметь приемущества если ваше приложение будет использовать только phalcon. Phalcon очень бедный фреймворк, он имеет базовый индустриальный набор компонентов и на этом все. Львиную долю логики вы будете обязаны дописать сами, и реализовав все что вам нужно собственноручно не о каких преимуществах C - расширения и речи не будет.

В своё время меня также как и других заинтересовал этот Фреймворк и в результате я был очень обескуражен. Программируя с phalcon вы заметите что не хватает очевидных вещей, а многие из них вы не сможете реализовать, так как многие классы или методы расширить не получится ввиду того, что они "финальные".

А если вы посмотрите в исходники на гитхабе, то поймёте что опыта у разработчиков не вагон. К примеру метод getUri в компоненте Request. На правый взгляд все хорошо?

Выбирая между Phalcon и Symfony, я бы предложил обратить внимание на последний.